# Spacemacs crashing on start with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: spacemacs, linux, ubuntu

I'm having a problem where every time I open Spacemacs it immediately crashes on Ubuntu 20.04. It was crashing for some actions with Magit and starting a CIDER REPL so I decided to do a fresh install. [Here](https://gist.github.com/TomLisankie/6b8614dac5d3698e8b7f01d8cb878121) is my .spacemacs file.

Comment: Can you load plain emacs with no init file (emacs -Q)?  If so, recursively bisect your spacemacs file until you isolate the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Addressed [here](https://github.com/alexmurray/emacs-snap/issues/12#issuecomment-629238158). It's an issue with Emacs 26 using libraries from back in 18.04 that are not present in 20.04.